# Property File Reading in Python

Tags: python, jython

I have a property file name called **server.properties**  and I need to read the property value using python.

**server.properties**

```
Server_IP=127.0.0.1
Server_Port=7001
Server_Url=t3://${Server_IP}:${Server_Port}
```

**server_detail.py**

```
propInputStream = FileInputStream("server.properties")
configProps = Properties()
configProps.load(propInputStream)

Server_IP=configProps.get("Server_IP") 
Server_Port=configProps.get("Server_Port")
Server_Url=configProps.get("Server_Url")

print(Server_IP)
print(Server_Port)
print(Server_Url)
```

**expected Result**

```
127.0.0.1
7001
t3:\\127.0.0.1:7001
```

**Actual Result**

```
127.0.0.1
7001
t3://${Server_IP}:${Server_Port}
```

**Server_IP** and **Server_Port** i could be able to get without any issue. How could I get the **Server_Url**. Is it possible to get the value?.
I need to use the **Server_Url** property using **ant**.

if the question has been already raised, please share the url. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what library are you using here? is this configparser?

Comment: Are you using [tag:jython]?

Comment: yes i m using jython

Comment: I am using  `from java.utl import Properties` @Keozon

Comment: I see you assigning `SERV_IP`, `USERNAME`,and `PASSWORD`, but printing `Server_IP`, `Server_Port`, and `Server_Url`.  That's strange.  You should post a minimal, complete, working program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @DavidCharles Its editing mistake, now i changed.

Comment: So, what exactly is wrong with this?  What did you do?  What was your expected result? And, what was your observed result?  I added the missing imports to your program and it seemed to work fine to me.

Comment: @DavidCharles , I ve updated the question with the expected and observed result. are you getting the expected result? then plz share.

Comment: I wouldn't expect your code to expand the references to `${Server_IP}` `${Server_Port}`.  Perhaps you could find that in the `PropertyHelpers` of the Ant libraries described here: https://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html. Or else, roll your own from the description there.